# Python virutalenv does nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

I am trying to run a simple python virtual environment and for some reason, nothing happens when I run a command. I open a new folder, cd into it, and run: `python3 -m venv tutorial-env` followed by `source tutorial-env/bin/activate`. All that happens is a new line is returned, but I am missing the `(tutorial-env)` at the beginning, and I am not in the virtual environment. Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this?

Some helpful info:
I'm on a mac

`python3 --version` returns `Python 3.9.5`

`which python` returns  `usr/local/bin/python3`